# Will a silicon spray really keep my weapon healthy?

Tags: weapons, larp, props, prop-maintenance

Silicon spray is often touted as keeping Latex larp weapons in good condition, but how effective is it? Is it worth the money? What environments does it protect against?

[image]

Please note, I mean this sort of weapon, not a boffer weapon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found they do help. Mostly they stop weapons sticking to each other and stop them picking up fluff.

Note that you can just buy a silicone spray from your local hardware store. The ones the larp weapon sellers sell aren't special in any way.

You can also use talcum powder to do the same thing, but it does tend to take the shine off the weapons (which I prefer for wood look weapons).

Answer (score 7):

Seeing as it makes the weapon slightly lubricated and stops snagging on other weapons so much (more so than talcum powder) It immensely decreases the chance of ripping if you accidentally snag your weapon on a tree or a wall. Not to mention silicone spray won't come off in rain and provides a larger amount of waterproofing, Seeing as talcum powder just washes off in the rain. You can get large bottles of it really cheaply (£6 ($9.68) for 1 liter) which is the same price the larp stores charge for the 60ml stuff. Also if i may add, as a larp weapon manufacturer I've noticed after a while talcum powder dries the latex out, whereas silicone spray keeps the latex healthy. We have this running saying in the workshop for stripping latex "it silicon-ed it will slip off like a nice tight sock, If it's talced you're in for the long run"

So simply yes, yes it's very good to silicone your weapon, it increases the life span by around 2 years for the latex.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a look at the [tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/about) and the [help](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help); they're a useful introduction to the site. And once you have 20+ rep, feel free to [join the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat)!

Answer (score 3):

In general, silicon based products of this kind are used as lubricants and sealants. I would imagine, in your case, that it would water proof the prop and make removal of other kinds of debris easier - similar to camping equipment. It may also help prevent minor abrasions - because it's lubricated.

Is it worth the money? That's something only you can decide. How valuable is that sword?